# trying to make a ScrollView loose is scroll control in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm looking to make an NSscrollview! lose its scrolling motion instantly

normally when u stop moving you still see the scroll bar 
and theres some sort of still active thing going on

I tried with lose first responder and have something claim first response 
but it didn't work
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well I am an iOS developer and not a Mac OS developer, but I can tell you on iOS we would wait for the UISCrollView to send the willBeginDecelerating message then hide the scroll bars and set the content offset to the current content offset with no animation to cancel the deceleration animation.  It looks like the equivalent notification for NSScrollView is [didEndLiveScrollNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscrollview/1403451-didendlivescrollnotification)

Comment: in swift how do i acess did endlivescroll notification

Comment: The usual way: NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myfunctionName), name: NSScrollView. didEndLiveScrollNotification, object: scrollView)

Comment: but is there  a way to kill its scrolling, i can hide the scrollbar but i cant disengage , it retains the control of the scroll untill i let it stop moving for 2-3 sec and id like to lose focus as soon as i call it to stop